# PHP File get contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm wondering if I can use file get contents to get only specific elements within the desired page. For instance: only store the content within the `<title></title>` tags or within the `<meta></meta>` tags and so forth. If it's not possible with file_get_contents what can I use to achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `explode()` function;

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.demo.com");
$explodedContent = explode("<title>", $content);
$explodedExplodedContent = explode("</title>", $explodedContent[1]);

echo $explodedExplodedContent[0]; // title of that page.
```

---

You can make it into a function;

```
function contentBetween($beginStr, $endStr, $contentURL){
  $content = file_get_contents($contentURL);
  $explodedContent = explode($beginStr, $content);
  $explodedExplodedContent = explode($endStr, $explodedContent[1]);

  return $explodedExplodedContent[0];
}

echo contentBetween("<title>", "</title>", "http://www.demo.com"); // usage.
```

See more about `explode()` f: http://php.net/manual/tr/function.explode.php

Comment: Clever thinking outside the box, I like it!

Comment: I agree! This is awesome, it works too! I just have one question--when I do the following it doesn't really give back the count of the string I'm trying to match:

`echo substr_count($explodedExplodedContent[0], 'Solving');`

I get back '21', not the expected '1'

Comment: This is wierd, can you share the full code or ask that as a new question and link it over here?